# JSF with CDI conversation scope bean continue coveersation in a popup window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, conversation-scope

I'm using cdi conversation scope bean with jsf, inside my jsf page I open a popup window , and I want to use the same conversation id as the parent window.

How can I do that? when I open the popup window and enter the bean, it is a new bean so the conversation does not exist. I want the new window to use the same conversation. Is possible to create this? How do I pass this conversation to the new page?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you open the new window, append a parameter with the conversation id in it.  I believe the param is `cid`

Comment: Yep, it's cid. Also if you're poping the window with a JSF component, you can add it as an f:param.